SharePoint 2013 search not crawling site
Our SharePoint 2013 search is no longer crawling our sites data. It reports 1 successes for the top-level site and that is it.


I have tried to re build search multiple times via powershell and through the gui with no success... it will crawl the user site with no issue

Do you have a working site collection with a homepage at the root of the URL https://connect-blur.com.au? Or it's just a root domain for sites under /sites or /teams?

Did the search suddenly stop crawling content before rebuilding the search components?

yes there is a fully functioning site collection
